# Intersect on HashSet results in compile error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, hashset, intersect

I've been trying to write a program, in which I want to use the intersection of two `HashSets`. Therefore I wrote the following code (for test purposes):

```
HashSet<int> test1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
HashSet<int> test2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
HashSet<int> intersect = new HashSet<int>();
intersect = test1.Intersect(test2);
```

Line 5 shows an error (code CS0266) which - that's C#'s suggestion - can be corrected by change the line to:
`intersect = (HashSet<int>)test1.Intersect(test2);`
But when I run the program, the error appears again. I literally have no clue why, even after searching for an answer.
I want to achieve a intersection in the mathematical sense, so that the result for the variable intersect should be `{ 1, 3, 5}`.
And what I found out - but couldn't test - is, that after using the `intersect`-method on `test1`, it changes the list in test1 to the intersection, is that true? If yes, is there any chance to avoid this? In my real program I don't want the variable to change into the intersection.

Should I just make a for-loop with an if-statement, to make my own intersection-method, or does this make the code worse?

As said, I tried to make use of C#'s suggestion, but this doesn't work either.
Because I'm a programming-beginner, I'm not really able to understand the definition of the intersect-method (because of this `IEnumerable` thing...), so I can't solve the problem using existend methods. And because I think my own method could be very inefficient, I don't to it my own. Furthermore I just want to understand, what's the problem. There are two HashSets, both containing integers, which should be intersected and saved in an extra variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0) returns a `IEnumerable<T>`. You can use [`IntersectWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-7.0), which modifies the current `HashSet<T>` object to contain only elements that are present in that object and in the specified collection:

```
HashSet<int> test1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
HashSet<int> test2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
test1.IntersectWith(test2); // we are altering test1 here
// test1 contains now [1, 3, 5]
```

or use the side-effect free Linq `Intersect()` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` and if you want it to be a new `HashSet<T>` just use a constructor:

```
HashSet<int> test1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
HashSet<int> test2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
HashSet<int> intersect = new HashSet<int>(test1.Intersect(test2));
// intersect contains now [1, 3, 5]
```

Remarks (from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-7.0))

> If the collection represented by the other parameter is a `HashSet<T>` collection with the same equality comparer as the current `HashSet<T>` object, this method is an O(n) operation. Otherwise, this method is an O(n + m) operation, where n is `Count` and m is the number of elements in other.

Basically in your case `IntersectWith()` is going to be more efficient!

Complete demo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HashSet<int> test1 = new HashSet<int>() {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        HashSet<int> test2 = new HashSet<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        HashSet<int> intersect = new HashSet<int>(test1.Intersect(test2));
        intersect.Dump();
        test1.IntersectWith(test2);
        test1.Dump();
    }
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yaQisD)

Comment: "side free" should be "side-effect free"?

Comment: @Lisa Glad it helps! if this question fixed your problem, you can accept this answer to help others.

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0) is a LINQ extension method that works with any kind of `IEnumerable<T>`. It returns `IEnumerable<T>`, so not a `HashSet<T>`. But since you have alrady two sets you want to use [`HashSet.IntersectWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-7.0)(more efficient since `O(n)`) with manipulates the first `HashSet<T>`:

```
test1.IntersectWith(test2); // test1 contains now [1, 3, 5]
```